# What are the marriage conditions for an offspring boy of sagotra vivah?

Tags: scripture, rituals, caste-system, marriage, gotra

Marriage in Kaliyug is to be within castes not outside, but not sagotra as well or else the offspring is Varnasankara. The pramana for this is given across Shrimad Bhagvad Gita and Puranas.
I am born of a Sagotra marriage(not within the same family but the same Gotra) of the same caste. I understand I am a Varnasankar.
What are the conditions for marriage of a sagotra(not within the same family but the same Gotra) Varnasankar as myself?

Please answer in Sastric Praman(referring the Sastra as well), will not entertain/tolerate 'what you feel Hinduism is about' or opinions putting themselves above Sastras.

Jai Shree Ram